# GTK after main loop

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have a problem as i cannot find proper solution in reference for making something happen after gtk_main(). This is my function for a simple bot that solves game but it won't run because it's not even starting. If i place gtk_main() after bot is done i will get a solved game so it works. Is there a function in gtk that lets me operate as i want in the gtk main loop? Here is the code:

```
void RunBot(struct Packet *packet){
gtk_main();
while(LookForWin(packet)==0){
    packet->data->color_number=ColorPredictor(packet);
    CheckColors(packet);
    RefreshBoard(packet->essentials,board,colors,BoardButtons,Board);
    printf("Running..\n");
}   }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: When you use a GUI toolkit like GTK+, you would be using events, timeouts, and idle callbacks, not writing code that runs straight through like you would in a console application. What do `packet` and `LookForWin()` do?

Comment: @andlabs Packet is a structure that contains informations about game state etc.  LookForWin() is simply a function checking if bot have already won. I managed to do this other way already, but i cannot make it refresh by every iteration of loop. Instead it refreshes randomly.

Answer (score 1):

As andlabs and mame98 pointed out, GUI toolkits expect your logic to be executed from callbacks that carry out a small amount of work and quickly relinquish control to the main loop. There is no "work after main loop", because the end of the main loop typically coincides application's exit.

Restructuring existing code to an event-driven style can be very hard when working with a large legacy code base. Fortunately, there is another option.

You can launch a thread ([using glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html#g-thread-new) to do it portably) and run your game logic in that thread, separate from the GUI thread. Inside the game thread, use `gdk_threads_add_idle()` to occasionally inform your GUI of changes. That should allow both the game code and the GUI thinking each runs the show.

Answer (score 0):

So in GTK you have events,signals and timeouts.

So if you want to call a function every x milliseconds, you should use

```
g_timeout_add (guint interval,
               GSourceFunc function,
               gpointer data);
```

Just look into the [official documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) for more details about this function.

`gtk_main` will run until you call `gtk_main_quit();` but you should only do this at the end of your application.